# Making localStorage and/or IndexedDB data offline permanent?

Tags: html, local-storage, indexeddb, offlineapps

Is it possible to make localStorage and/or IndexedDB offline data permanent?

I am planning to make a completely offline HTML5 app and want the data to never get deleted, unless and otherwise the user knowingly does so.

I do not want the data to be deleted even after the app is closed, system is shutdown or something like CCleaner is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking is [persistent storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/#persistent) as defined in [Quota Management API](http://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/). Currently none of the browser implemented it.

However IndexedDB data, even thought temporary storage, are persist over application life cycle.